How to change Plan Subscription?
I'm using this API to change the subscription from monthly to weekly.
API endpoint: https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}/revise
Plan ID: P-1GB4504364996494GM5HWL5Y
Subscription ID: I-C4REH9PENL26
I've tried this Code Snippet:
$planAPIUrl = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-C4REH9PENL26/revise";

$new_plan = [ 'plan_id' => "P-1GB4504364996494GM5HWL5Y", ];

$APIrequest = wp_remote_post($planAPIUrl, [
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'body' => json_encode($new_plan)
]);

if (is_wp_error($APIrequest)) {
    return 'Error getting subscription plans: ' . $APIrequest->get_error_message();
}

$APIresponse = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($APIrequest), true);

i'm getting this error when executed:
{
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "f963655a5bde9",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}```

What am I missing? Is there any thing else I need to mention in my $new_plan, And in doc it also mentioned "This type of update requires the buyer's consent.".

The most likely cause of RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND is if the subscription belongs to a different app (client ID and secret)

It's on the same app I have already checked.
